# import SSL Certificate from IIS to Tomcat

Tags: iis, tomcat, ssl-certificate

Can we import the IIS CSR to the java keytool?

Comment: Belongs on ServerFault.com

Answer (score 2):

The title of the question leads me to believe you are trying to take a certificate's private/public key from IIS and use it on a Tomcat Web Server.  If this is the case then you will need to first export the certificate (both private and public keys) into a .PFX file, [convert the .PFX file into a .PEM file](http://support.theplanet.com/kb/controlpanels/plesk/how-convert-ssl-cert-pem-pfx-format), and then copy the .PEM file into the correct location for Tomcat to use...

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot, but I can't think of a good reason to do this. Are you sure that is what you want to do?